# How to generate batch number in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, row-number

Any idea on how to generate batch numbers into a `batch_number` column in SQL Server table from 1 to 3 and repeat it again as shown below in the script?

Thanks in advance

```
Declare @mTestTable table
(
     id int,
     city varchar(50),
     batch_number int
)

--Insert some sample data
Insert into @mTestTable values (1, 'London')
Insert into @mTestTable values (2, 'Karachi')
Insert into @mTestTable values (3, 'New York')
Insert into @mTestTable values (4, 'Melbourne')
Insert into @mTestTable values (5, 'Beijing')
Insert into @mTestTable values (6, 'Tokyo')
Insert into @mTestTable values (7, 'Moscow')
```

I need to generate batch number from 1 to 3 and repeat it again.

```
Id  City        Batch_Number
1   London      1
2   Karachi     2
3   New York    3
4   Melbourne   1
5   Beijing     2
6   Tokyo       3
7   Moscow      1
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `row_number()` and some arithmetic:

```
with toupdate as (
      select t.*, 1 + ((row_number() over (order by id) - 1) % 3) as new_batch_no
      from testtable
     )
update toupdate
    set batch_number = new_batch_number;
```

Answer (score -1):

```
update @mTestTable
set batch_number = (id-1) % 3 + 1
```

If the IDs won't be sequential, then one way to do it is using a cursor passing through it. Simply count the rows one by one and `update` the appropriate batch number.

Comment: `id%3` when it is `!=0` and `id` otherwise?